# Launch Google Maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm trying to launch Google maps from my application. I'm using:

```
GeoPoint center = _mapView.getMapCenter(); 

Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+center.getLatitudeE6()+","+center.getLongitudeE6()); 

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Launching Google Maps with Uri: ("+uri+")"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

startActivity(intent);
```

I tested it with a map centered on somewhere in NYC, however Google maps opens not centered there. 
I followed Android Developer's site reference to use: "geo:latitude,longitude" pattern.

the log that you see prints:

```
Launching Google Maps with Uri: (geo:40763500,-73979305)
```

anyone knows what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+(center.getLatitudeE6()/1E6)+","+(center.getLongitudeE6()/1E6));
```

The [geo: Uri](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-00) format takes decimal latitude/longitude and not E6 format (degrees * 1E6).

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide by 1E6 since [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) doesn't return a double.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+(center.getLatitudeE6()/1E6)+","+(center.getLongitudeE6()/1E6));
```

I like this way personally where daddr would be `(center.getLatitudeE6()/1E6)+","+(center.getLongitudeE6()/1E6)`

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr="+saddr+"&daddr="+daddr+"&hl=en")));
```