# How can I convert E6 formatted locations to Windows Phone GeoCoordinate objects?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

I am trying to create plot some push pins on map using `GeoCoordinate` as location for pushpins.

From an online api I get the location in E6 format .

`[{"lat":39453787,"lng":-361946},{"lat":37360100,"lng":-5986312},{"lat":53330662,"lng":-6260177},{"lat":36700744,"lng":137212211},]`

But windows phone 7 `GeoCoordinate` accepts lat as -90 to 90 and lgn as -180 to 180 .

How do I convert these values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has actually come up before, the answer is to divide by 1e6 :)

[Launch Google Maps app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553251/launch-google-maps-app)

Comment: this goes out of range latitude  -1000000000.0 longitude   153022570.0

Comment: To handle extreme cases, you should probably wrap the values manually.  i.e.:  while( lat < -180.0 ) { lat += 180.0; } as a simple example.