# Android launch system apps

Tags: android, android-intent, system, package

Hey This is probably a pretty newbie question, but anyway. How can i start applications that are pre-innstalled on the system. For example: lets say i want to start/launch the maps application or the default contacts/calling app on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

`Intent`s are the way to start other activities. I recommend to read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) how-to.

Comment: How do I get Intent for for example maps application and calling application that are pre innstalled ?

Comment: The code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553251/launch-google-maps-app) should help