# How to open **Google Maps** application from my current application?

Tags: android, google-maps

How I can open **Google Maps** application on button click event from my current application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Google Maps app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553251/launch-google-maps-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a **Intent**.

Here you have a **real example**

https://web.archive.org/web/20200710235813/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/launching-other-application-using-code.html

Here you have an **theoric example**

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Here you have the Android **documentation**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 5):

use below line

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/";
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
```

that will redirect in map application.

Answer (score 3):

You can open google maps with intent giving your starting point and end point.

```
Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
        .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
                + Constants.latitude + ","
                + Constants.longitude + "&daddr="
                + latitude + "," + longitude));
startActivity(navigation);
```

This opens any maps application. Means a browser or google maps application. If you just want google maps and get rid of the dialog you can give the intent a hint as to which package you want to use.

Before the `startActivity()` add this:

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by specifying "intent-filters" in your AndroidManifes.xml; for more on how to launch google applications from your application see this link: [Intents List: Invoking Google Applications on Android Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.w);    
Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     view.loadUrl("http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl");
                    }
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:`Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to call **google maps** from my current app.

```
String SettingsPage = "com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity";

                try
                {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);             
                intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(SettingsPage));             
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );             
                startActivity(intent); 
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                 Log.e("Activity Not Found","");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                     Log.e("Activity Not Found",""+e);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this.
hope it works for you:

```
 Button showMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_showMap);
 showMap .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
 public void onClick(View v){
 Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:"+ latitude +","+ longitude ));
 startActivity(i);
 }
 });
```