# User navigation on google maps - how to?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, navigation

I'm an averagely experienced Android programmer.
I'm currently working on an app that includes the google maps API and among the activities there are two views that include a map fragment. Now I want someone to be able to navigate on one of those views, called mapActivtiy. It basicly consists of a map, that's all. After choosing a location in another view, I want the map to display the direction from the users position (which I already know) and the target's location.

Now, in iOS I'd just throw in the `MKDirections` stuff from the MapKit framework, but I seem to be unable to find something equivalent for android. Is there any API or something for wayfinding and navigation on the map? If so, where to look for it?

Just to clearify this: I know I can call the google navigation app from my app, but I don't (really) want to do that, I'd prefer staying within my context. Using the navigation app is more of a last resort.

Does anyone have a smart adivce for me?
Any idea would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17784088/1777090)

Comment: @PurpleDroid: Thanks already, we'll keep that as a back up but to be honest, that's sadly pretty much not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to do it on _my_ map, not on the google intent. Basicly, I just want to add the "graphic" of the routing onto my activty, not throw a new activity.