# How to implement first person view in android google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android application i want to implement first person view. Please check following URL for first person View -

[Google First Person View](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-toggle-first-person-view-in-google-maps-navigati-1646730312)

I found one link which redirects to first person view please check -

[Google Maps Navigation - Using Google Navigation in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490563/google-maps-navigation-using-google-navigation-in-android-application)

But in it we don't have control over navigation view or first person view. It redirects to google's default first person view. I want to implement it manually. Means in which we can pass latitude and longitude dynamically(from Server)

Is there any way to implement first person view Pro-grammatically, in which we have command over view ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create turn-by-turn GPS navigation app on Android using Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531391/is-it-possible-to-create-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-app-on-android-using-google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly, how to achieve that view, but you can do one thing, that is whatever orientation's value you are getting from your server or any gps device , pass it into `bearing()` method of `CameraPosition` and set `tilt` also, like following -

```
       CameraPosition cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latlng)
              .zoom(zoomvalue).bearing(orientation).tilt(tiltvalue).build();
              googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPos), null);
```

by doing this your map will be rotate according to value of orientation. and if you pass value of orientation into `rotation(orientation)` method of marker then your marker will rotate according to value.

Hope it'll help you.